# Есть ли аналог события времени существования Loaded(wpf) в Avalonia UI?

Tags: wpf, xaml, avalonia

Возникла необходимость в переводе wpf приложения на Avalonia. Приложение при запуске загружает некоторые нужные данные(в обработчике события Loaded). Вопрос в том, есть ли аналогичные события времени существования  элемента Window в Avalonia UI?

Answer (score 0):

Можно это делать по событию `Initialized` или `Opened`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.